# Unrecognized PC has set up a Homegroup on my network

Tags: networking, homegroup

I have been trying to learn mobile app development and so I set up a local server on my Windows 10 PC. But none of the devices on my network could access the ip of the server or even ping it. But besides the PC, they could all ping each other. So I went to *Control Panel -> Network and Internet* and tried to see what I could do about it (although I know zilch about networks).

The first thing I thought might be helpful was set up a Homegroup. But I found out that someone else had already set one up which I have no access to. (Wish I could post screenshots, but I lack the reputation points). Basically it says "Kryuchkov on KRYUCHKOV-PC has created a homegroup on the network". I know of no such PC named that. But it asked me for the password and assured me I could find it on the kryuchkov computer if I needed to look it up. But I can't do that.

Next I went to "Network" in file explorer and saw that besides my PC, it was also showing an ANDREWMARKUS-PC and a media device named ANDREWMARKUS-PC, as well. But none of my other devices on my wifi network (phones, ipad, other pc) were shown. There wasn't a KRYUCHKOV-PC listed though, for some reason.

The last thing I did was log into my router/gateway ip and look at the connected devices there. It showed all my devices (phones, pc etc etc) as well as Andrew Markus's stuff, and some alphanumericly named ones (eg: 08:68:66:39:48:f1) in the "offline devices" section. Again there was no KRYUCHKOV-PC, so I don't know how that PC fits into the equation.

I have found some resources on how to get unauthorized users off networks, but I'm having trouble finding anything about how to dislodge an unwanted homegroup. How do I get my network free from these parasites? And also, how might this (if at all) relate to my original issue which was that my PC is isolated from my other devices and cannot seem to expose its local server to them?

Comment: First thing you need to do is secure your Wireless network...I am surprised you haven't been handed some Cease and Desist letters by now...I think once you do that and your neighbors can't connect to your network your other problems should go away.

Comment: @TheXed Cease and Desist what?

Comment: a letter from the copyright holders from your neighbors downloading pirated movies/music/books....that basically says stop or we are going to sue you...